# How do I use a web form to enter data to mysql db using an array?

Tags: php, mysql, database, arrays

Here's the target table:

```
**trophies**
game_name
tr_name
tr_description
tr_color
tr_ach_value
```

Here's the form:

```
    <form action="update.php" method="post">
Game Name:  <input name="game_name" type="text" size="25" maxlength="255" /><br></br>
Release Date:  <input name="release_date" type="text" size="25" /><p></p>
</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>Trophies:</p>
Trophy Name:    <input name="tr_name" type="text" size="50" maxlength="255" /><br/>
Descripton:     <input name="tr_desc" type="text" size="50" maxlength="255" /><br/>
Trophy Color:   <select name="tr_color">
  <option value="Bronze">Bronze</option>
  <option value="Silver">Silver</option>
  <option value="Gold">Gold</option>
  <option value="Platinum">Platinum</option>
  <option value="Hidden">Hidden</option>
</select>
Points: <input name="tr_ach_value" type="text" size="4" maxlength="4" /><p></p>

Trophy Name:    <input name="tr_name" type="text" size="50" maxlength="255" /><br/>
Descripton:     <input name="tr_desc" type="text" size="50" maxlength="255" /><br/>
Trophy Color:   <select name="tr_color">
  <option value="Bronze">Bronze</option>
  <option value="Silver">Silver</option>
  <option value="Gold">Gold</option>
  <option value="Platinum">Platinum</option>
  <option value="Hidden">Hidden</option>
</select>
Points: <input name="tr_ach_value" type="text" size="4" maxlength="4" /><p></p>

Trophy Name:    <input name="tr_name" type="text" size="50" maxlength="255" /><br/>
Descripton:     <input name="tr_desc" type="text" size="50" maxlength="255" /><br/>
Trophy Color:   <select name="tr_color">
  <option value="Bronze">Bronze</option>
  <option value="Silver">Silver</option>
  <option value="Gold">Gold</option>
  <option value="Platinum">Platinum</option>
  <option value="Hidden">Hidden</option>
</select>
Points: <input name="tr_ach_value" type="text" size="4" maxlength="4" /><p></p>


Trophy Name:    <input name="tr_name" type="text" size="50" maxlength="255" /><br/>
Descripton:     <input name="tr_desc" type="text" size="50" maxlength="255" /><br/>
Trophy Color:   <select name="tr_color">
  <option value="Bronze">Bronze</option>
  <option value="Silver">Silver</option>
  <option value="Gold">Gold</option>
  <option value="Platinum">Platinum</option>
  <option value="Hidden">Hidden</option>
</select>
Points: <input name="tr_ach_value" type="text" size="4" maxlength="4" /><p></p>

<input name="submit" type="button" value="submit" />
</form>
```

I'm trying to get the multiple trophy records each with the same game_name inserted into the table trophies.  Would I use an array for this?  If so could you show me an example of how?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Name your input fields like this

```
Trophy Name:    <input name="trophy[0][name]" type="text" size="50" maxlength="255" /><br/>
Descripton:     <input name="trophy[0][desc]" type="text" size="50" maxlength="255" /><br/>
Trophy Color:   <select name="trophy[0][color]">
  <option value="Bronze">Bronze</option>
  <option value="Silver">Silver</option>
  <option value="Gold">Gold</option>
  <option value="Platinum">Platinum</option>
  <option value="Hidden">Hidden</option>
</select>
Points: <input name="trophy[0][ach_value]" type="text" size="4" maxlength="4" /><p></p>
```

Just increase the number by one for each new set of data.
Hope that helped.

Edit:

The PHP code would be like this:

```
<?php
    foreach($_POST['trophy'] as $trophy) {
        $sql = "INSERT INTO trophies (game_name, tr_name, tr_description, tr_color, tr_ach_value) VALUES ('".$_POST['game_name']."', '".$trophy['name']."', '".$trophy['desc']."', '".$trophy['color']."', '".$trophy['ach_value']."')";
        mysql_query($sql);
    }
?>
```

Comment: Thanks Guys.  What would the code be to then insert the array data into the table?

Comment: Would it be:
`code`
sql = 'INSERT INTO trophies (game_name, tr_name, tr_description, tr_color, tr_ach_value) VALUES (game_name, tr_name, tr_desc, tr_color, tr_ach_value)';
`code`

Comment: No problem :) And also don't forget to sanitize the values before inserting it into the database ;-) See here for details http://www.w3schools.com/PHP/php_filter.asp

Answer (score 1):

use name[] as field name

```
  <imput name="tr_name[]" ...
```

in php all fields using a [] final in the name is an array at server side, so in your php you can iterate your multiples tr_name inside $_POST['tr_name'] variable, etc.

Comment: Yeah but the resulting $_POST array is kind of ungrouped. Just a personal preference I like my values to appear together in one array ;-)